# How to make button show when minimizing screen?

Tags: javascript, html, css, angular

I would like the search icon to show all the time even when the screen is minimized. 
As you can see, when you minimize the screen, the search icon hides.

How can I make it show using CSS?

Please see example:
[Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/navbar-stackoverflow?file=app%2Fapp.component.html)

Comment: Can you explain a little more about your requirement? you want to see search bar even after which screen is minimized?

Comment: no i would like to see the search icon. Please click on the link, you will see the search icon

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try adding flex-wrap property to the parent as like:

```
nav {
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
}
```

Also,remove fixed height to navbar :

```
@media (max-width: 599px){
    .mat-toolbar-row, .mat-toolbar-single-row {
        height: auto !important; 
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you; this helped! The key was setting the display.

Answer (score 0):

You can use flex box and use wrap functionality:
https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/f/flex-wrap/

**flex-wrap:** nowrap | wrap | wrap-reverse

**CSS**

```
.flex-container {
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}
```

Look at their code pen that demonstrates how the wrap works when the screen size reduces (I think you mentioned it as minimized) the search will jump to the next line (wrap):
https://codepen.io/team/css-tricks/pen/1ea1ef35d942d0041b0467b4d39888d3

From **mat-toolbar** perspective on how to Positioning toolbar content:
The toolbar does not perform any positioning of its content. This gives the user full power to position the content as it suits their application.

A common pattern is to position a title on the left with some actions on the right. This can be easily accomplished with display: flex:

CSS & HTML

```
.example-fill-remaining-space {
  /* This fills the remaining space, by using flexbox. 
     Every toolbar row uses a flexbox row layout. */
  flex: 1 1 auto;
}


<mat-toolbar color="primary">
  <span>Application Title</span>
  <!-- This fills the remaining space of the current row -->
  <span class="example-fill-remaining-space"></span>
  <span>Right Aligned Text</span>
</mat-toolbar>
```

https://material.angular.io/components/toolbar/overview#positioning-toolbar-content